# getSupportActionBar() crashes my Android app

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I use getSupportActionBar() on my Android app it crashes the app.

Here is the code:-

```
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Activity 2");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Either will crash the app.

I use this Import

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

Help would be appreciated

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

Any use of getSupportActionBar() will crash the app

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire class, not just two lines. Also, please post the Java stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly without further details it could be anything. First thing that comes to mind is to check that your activity extends from AppCompatActivity.

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
// Your activity code
}
```

Also make your app theme inherits from a theme compatible with AppCompatActivity like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

And that your theme is applied to your application is the Manifest

```
<application
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```